# What does synchronization means in terms of StringBuilder and StringBuffer classes?

Tags: java, multithreading, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I am quite confused with the term 'synchronized', I've got following from java documentation.

> A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API
>   compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of
>   synchronization. This class is designed for use as a drop-in
>   replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was
>   being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where
>   possible, it is recommended that this class **be used in preference to
>   StringBuffer** as it will be faster under most implementations.

As I know synchronization relates to threads and the way of their access.

Lets say, I have a web application that is utilizing StringBuilder in one of its methods,

- What does no guarantee of synchronisation mean here?
- Should I be worried about anything? When should I be worried about multiple threads? Any examples?
- When should I care about guaranteed and non-guaranteed
  synchronisation?
- What is an example of having a web application with multiple threads?

An example would be highly appreciated.

**Please note I know multiple thread access require synchronization because they need to have access to the same data! I need to have an example for that.**

Answer (score 5):

You should care about synchronization if more than one thread can have access to the same `StringBuilder` instance at the same time. In such case you should consider using `StringBuffer` instead.

For example, here you should consider using a `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` :

```
public class Test implements Runnable
{
    public static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public void run ()
    {
        Test.sb.append ("something");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // start two threads
        new Thread (new Test()).start();
        new Thread (new Test()).start();
    }
}
```

If you have a `StringBuilder` instance which is local to some method, there is no risk of another thread accessing it, so you don't need synchronization, and using `StringBuilder` would be more efficient.

Comment: would you give me an example for that? what do you mean by multiple threads in my web application example?

Comment: @DanielNewtown For example, if you have a static StringBuilder instance in some class, and your web application starts multiple threads, and more than one of them can access that StringBuilder instance at the same time, you should synchronize access to it.

Comment: Thanks then whats an example of having a web application with multiple threads?

Comment: @DanielNewtown I added an example of a simple application having multiple threads.

Comment: it would be implements Runnable

Comment: @Michal No, I intended my code snippet to be an example where using StringBuilder can lead to problems. StringBuilder is the not thread safe class.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronized keyword doesn't show up in the generated JavaDoc, but if you open the source code of StringBuffer, you'll see that each public method which can change the state of the instance actually has synchronized keyword in its signature.

For example the [getChars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#getChars-int-int-char:A-int-) method

```
   /**
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dst,
                                      int dstBegin)
    {
        super.getChars(srcBegin, srcEnd, dst, dstBegin);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a variable `myElement` as a StringBuffer. Your application has a news feed from different newspapers, and you have multiple threads filling that up from various sources. 
Threads will locate their new information in the `DOM element` that `myElement` describes. Once they locate it, they modify `myElement`, so other thread knows where to locate the new piece of news. Thanks to synchronization, a thread will block another one when they have access to the same variable, but not in this case, so it can happen that one thread reads `myElement` when it is being modified and is half complete, and gets a reference to a part of the DOM that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringBuffer` almost never makes sense:

- ***most of the time, you can use a local `StringBuilder` variable and there is only one thread involved so no synchronzation is required***
- in the rare cases where the `StringBuffer`/`Builder` variable is a field and is shared across threads, the `StringBuffer` guarantee will probably not be enough anyway because each call to `append` will be ordered randomly

Imagine:

```
public void m(String a, String b) {
  sharedStringBuffer.append(a).append(b);
}
```

`StringBuffer` doesn't give you the guarantee that each call to m will result in `a` and `b` to be adjacent as another call to append may have happened in the middle...

So bottom line:

- either the variable is not shared: use a `StringBuilder`
- either it is shared and you probably need more than the synchronization of `StringBuffer`: use a `StringBuilder` with appropriate synchronization.

Comment: @DanielNewtown a synchronization policy that is appropriate for your use case - there is no general rule...

Answer (score 0):

You should care about it when you have a StringBuffer that is shared berween threads. If you are not sharing thus no race condition van happen and you are free to use StringBuilder.

Comment: Give me an example please.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way. Let's say you have a class which share an instance of StringBuilder between it's method. Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    public void add(String str) {
         this.str.append(str);
    }

    public void remove(int start, int end) {
         this.str.delete(start, end);
    }

}
```

Because this instance is share between non-synchronized method so if two threads at the same time call this methods the data won't be the data you are expected. It is the meaning of not guaranteed synchronization.

Instead of using StringBuilder you can use StringBuffer which supports synchronization.

```
public class MyClass {
    private StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

    public void add(String str) {
         this.str.append(str);
    }

    public void remove(int start, int end) {
         this.str.delete(start, end);
    }

}
```

As you know synchronization has some performance issues but it is necessary in case of multi threading.

Usually StringBuilder can be used as local variables.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer is not needed unless you are sharing it between threads, in which case, synchronization makes sense. StringBuilder is mutable, which means it's state can be viewed inconsistently between threads. StringBuffer does not suffer from this problem (should it need to at all).

StringBuilder is like StringBuffer v2. It was added to the Java libraries after the phase where developers were paranoid about thread-safety and required thread safety when they did not need it.

As for the bolded portion of the javadoc you posted, synchronization has overhead, and because StringBuilder is non-synchronized, it does not take a performance hit.

The synchronization guarantee means that because it is "compatible with StringBuffer", you may expect StringBuilder to be synchronized, but that *may* not be the case (such as when the JIT optimizes StringBuffer, for example).

You should not worry about non-guaranteed or guaranteed synchronization. What you should worry about is using StringBuffer when it is shared. Whether or not StringBuilder is synchronized or not synchronized, as long as it is shared only within one thread or protected accordingly, you should not encounter any problems.

You should worry about using StringBuffer here:

```
final StringBuffer append = new StringBuffer();

void append() {
    append.append(". ");
}

new Thread(() -> append()).start();
new Thread(() -> append()).start();
```

You can see that it is accessed by two threads. Notice how it declared final for initialization safety.